# PostgreSQL HSTORE GIN query

Tags: arrays, postgresql, operators, postgresql-9.2, hstore

I can't figure out how to re-write this query using arrays for the test cases:

```
--explain
SELECT  COUNT(id)
FROM    (
    SELECT  T.id
    FROM    product2 AS T
    WHERE   (ext @> 'p01=>1' OR ext @> 'p01=>2')
    AND (ext @> 'p02=>1' OR ext @> 'p02=>2' OR ext @> 'p02=>3')
    AND (ext @> 'p03=>2' OR ext @> 'p03=>3' OR ext @> 'p03=>4' OR ext @> 'p03=>5' OR ext @> 'p03=>6')
) T
```

I'm looking for something like `ext @> 'p01=[1,2]'`. The [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html) doesn't indicate if this is possible.

Note: even if ranges were possible, I don't want them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will extract the values for key 'p01' and return TRUE if any matches are found in the array. Is that what you are after?

```
SELECT ('p01=>1,p01=>2,p02=>1,p02=>3,p02=>5'::hstore -> 'p01')::INTEGER = ANY(ARRAY[1,2,3,4,5])
```

Modified to look like the original query

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM    (
        SELECT t2.id
        FROM product2 t2
        WHERE (ext::HSTORE -> 'p01')::INTEGER = ANY(ARRAY[1,2])
        AND (ext::HSTORE -> 'p02')::INTEGER = ANY(ARRAY[1,2,3])
        AND (ext::HSTORE -> 'p03')::INTEGER = ANY(ARRAY[2,3,4,5,6])
        ) t;
```

That gives unexpected results?

Comment: I get different results if I implement this. I am after what you state.

Comment: I had *just* worked out something very similar.
((ext->'p01')::int = ANY ('{1,2}'::int[]))

Comment: Final: ((ext->'p01')::int = ANY(ARRAY[1,2]))